# Standard ORDER BY's doesnt work on my query

Tags: mysql

I Want to Order the search results by relevancy but standard techniques doesn't work on my code because it is doing double search check in the query to find the ones with 'Match' and 'Like'  as well. How can I perform it with the code below;

```
$qry = mysql_query("
SELECT * 
  FROM workdb 
 WHERE publish = 'Yes' 
   AND MATCH (workname, keyword1, keyword2, keyword3)  AGAINST ('*$searched*' IN BOOLEAN 
MODE) 
    OR publish = 'Yes' 
   AND (workname LIKE '%$searched%' 
     OR keyword1 LIKE '%$searched%' 
     OR keyword2 LIKE '%$searched%' 
     OR keyword3 LIKE '%$searched%') 
  LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage
");
```

**EDIT:** I want to display the result from most relevant to least relevant. The reason I use Math and LIKE both is to not miss any matched elements from the search.

**EDIT2:** OK lets make it clear, I have a workname and 3 keywords in database rows so I want to get the ones with the Best match to my searched text/word and put them into an order to most LIKE to least LIKE/ Most matches to Least Matches.

Comment: Where is this poisonous book or tutorial that suggests using mysql_query? And see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please edit your question and tell us where you tried to add an ORDER BY in your query, and what happened. Was an error message displayed, did it not do what you wanted, or what? Thanks.

Comment: you can use 

$qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM workdb WHERE publish='Yes' AND MATCH 
(workname, keyword1, keyword2, keyword3)  AGAINST ('%$searched%' IN BOOLEAN 
MODE) OR publish='Yes' AND (workname LIKE '%$searched%' OR keyword1 LIKE 
'%$searched%' OR keyword2 LIKE '%$searched%' OR keyword3 LIKE '%$searched%')
ORDER BY workname asc
LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage");

this is demo code

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam - please consider making that an answer. Thanks.

Comment: 1) if you use a mixed mode, you need to come up with a way to calculate relevancy based on your business requirements. We can help implementing that, but you need to come up with the idea and you also need to try to implement it. 2) Why do you search twice? 3) Boolean fulltext search uses the `*`, not the `%` for wildcard operation, and it cannot have a wildcard at the beginning of the word

Comment: @Shadow the reason I do twice check is; sometimes  'Match' escapes some word and sometimes 'Like' escapes. When I use both i definitely grabbing everything with fulltext or word based. I will chagen '%' to '*' thank you but I stiil need to order by relevancy

Comment: @BobJarvis ordering by a field value is not the same as ordering by relevancy

Comment: @GüneySaramalı let me reiterate: you need to define relevancy in this case. That's a business decision, not a programming one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is here if anyone have the same problem. Nobody understand me instead they downvote.

```
    mysql_query("SELECT *, 
(MATCH (workname)  AGAINST ('*$searched*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
AND 
(workname LIKE '%$searched%')) 
AS relevancy 
FROM workdb 
WHERE publish='Yes' 
AND 
(MATCH (workname, keyword1, keyword2, keyword3)  AGAINST ('*$searched*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
OR  
(workname LIKE '%$searched%' OR keyword1 LIKE '%$searched%' OR keyword2 LIKE '%$searched%' OR keyword3 LIKE '%$searched%')) 
ORDER BY relevancy DESC 
LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage");
```